# When i use a sql command in a for loop for uploading multiple rows in an excel file it doesnt work...it just uploads the first row

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpexcel

When i use a sql command in a for loop for uploading multiple rows in an excel file it doesnt work...it just uploads the first row
This is my Code to save the entries into sql database...it  is an old project where many functions were deprecated..i have replaced almost all of them but still it doesnt work..the upload file will be an excel file with multiple rows..only the first row data gets saved in DB

```
<?php

if ($_FILES['userfile']['size'] > 0) {
    $fileName = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
    $tmpName = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];
    $fileSize = $_FILES['userfile']['size'];
    $fileType = $_FILES['userfile']['type'];

    $fp = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
    $content = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
    $content = addslashes($content);
    fclose($fp);

    $fileName = addslashes($fileName);


    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);

    define('EOL', (PHP_SAPI == 'cli') ? PHP_EOL : '<br />');

    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

    /** Include PHPExcel_IOFactory */
    require_once '../Classes/PHPExcel.php';
    require_once '../Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
    require_once '../db.php';


    if (!file_exists("$tmpName")) {
        exit("Contacts File does not exist" . EOL);
    }
    $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReaderForFile("$tmpName");
    $objReader->setReadDataOnly(false);
    $objPHPExcel  = $objReader->load("$tmpName");
    $objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
    $sql = '';
    $i = 0;
    $status = 0;
    foreach ($objWorksheet->getRowIterator() as $row) {
        if ($row->getRowIndex() > 1) {
            $cellIterator = $row->getCellIterator();
            $cellIterator->setIterateOnlyExistingCells(false);
            $values = array();
            foreach ($cellIterator as $cell) {
                $cellval = trim(iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1", $cell->getValue()), " \t\n\r\0\x0B\xA0\xA0* ");
                if (empty($cellval)) {
                    $cellval = "NULL";
                    array_push($values, $cellval);
                } else {
                    array_push($values, '"' . $cellval . '"');
                } // if (is_numeric($cellval))
            } // foreach ($cellIterator as $cell)
            // build the insert statement from the values in the cells.
            $mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
            $sql = "Call Insert_Contact(" . $values[0] . "," . $values[1] . "," . $values[2] . "," . $values[3] . "," . $values[4] . "," . $values[5] . "," . $values[6] . "," . $values[7] . "," . $values[8] . "," . $values[9] . "," . $values[10] . "," . $values[11] . ",@inserted);";
            $qry1 = "SELECT @inserted AS status";
            $mysqli->query($sql);
            $stmt = $mysqli->query($qry1);
            $row1 = $stmt->fetch_assoc();
            $status = $row1['status'];
            $stmt->close();
            echo mysqli_error($mysqli);
        }
        $i = $i + $status;
    }
    if (!mysqli_error($mysqli)) {
        echo $i . " contacts Uploaded";
    } else {
        echo    mysqli_error($mysqli);
        //include 'library/closedb.php';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: You don't expect us to read this wall of code and tell you what question to ask, do you?

Comment: End-of-line terminator problem?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use "LOAD DATA Statement" bellow

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$tmp_file_path' IGNORE
                INTO TABLE tmp_table
                FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
                ENCLOSED BY '\"'
                LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
                IGNORE 1 ROWS
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html

If you do not want all data from your file then create a temporary table and all data of the file in that table after that you can simply insert data from that temporary table like this

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO `tbl1` ( col1, col2, col3)   
SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM tmp_table
```

Comment: You are talking about CSV file while the question asked about Excel file

Comment: it working my bad it was an error in db